# Finding the supremum and infimum of a set of sums of positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $n \geq 3$ be an arbitrarily fixed integer. Take all possible
> finite sequences $(a_1,..,a_n)$ of positive numbers. Let
>
> $$ S = \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} }  :
>  a_{n+1}=a_1, \; \; a_{n+2} = a_2\right\} $$
>
> Find $\sup S $ and $\inf S$

### Attempt:

My idea is to use the fact that $\sup (A + B) = \sup A + \sup B $. IF we let $S_k = \{ \dfrac{ a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2} } \}$, then we observe that

$$ S = S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n $$

So, let us concentrate on $S_k$. Notice that since $a_k \geq 0 $, then

$$ \dfrac{a_k }{a_k + a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} } \leq \dfrac{a_k}{a_k} = 1 $$

So $1$ is an upper bound for $S_k$. I am having difficulties trying to prove that $1$ is indeed $\sup S_k$. In other words, we must show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $s \in S_k$ such that $1- \epsilon < s $.

If we suppose otherwise: $\exists \epsilon_0$ so that $\forall s \in S_k$, then $1 + \epsilon_0 \geq s$ but this seems to led me nowhere. How can I choose and $s \in S_k$ that would lead to. contradiction?? Am I overcomplicating this problem?

Comment: What are the $a_k$? Positive integers? Positive reals? Something else?

Comment: positive numbers

Comment: @James, if you were asked whether $a_k$ are reals, then the comment _positive numbers_ is confusing... E. g., there is no total order in $\mathbb C$, so... ??????

Comment: Also, $(\ldots)$ allows repeating, so $a_k\gt 0$ and $\frac{0}{0}\ne 1$...